# Tracking Salesforce object changes - alternative tool for event monitoring

Tags: debugging, debug-logs, event-monitoring

Is it possible to determine what process/trigger/code made a change to an object in SalesForce?

We have cases being created by Email2Case and there instances where we want to blank out the account being populated.

There is a process builder process that successfully sets the Account to null - only to be changed back to original value.

Using field tracking can see that email comes in and creates a case- account is set, account is set to null and then it's set back to original value.

Debug logs are set automation account, Automated Process and Platform integration user, as well as for a few triggers (these are managed code) and am not seeing anything useful generated when a case is created.

Noticed Change Data Capture feature - this seems like a bit of effort to enable a trigger to display change events - but would it track what actually triggered the change?

Answer (score 0):

Altought it involves several functionalities, Salesforce Shield provides event monitoring in the granular way you describe. Alternatively if you are confident with development, you can deploy a custom tool to log (i.e. in an custom object) all jobs/triggers executions with the respective lastmodifiedby field logged.